# PHP crazy behavior on mount

Tags: windows, bash, mount, php, smbfs

I have a mount to my windows machine on a linux machine.
When I try to run any php scripts there it says it's not found, however, when i copy the files to the local storage it runs with no problem. I tried to mount using exec,rw options nothing changes this behavior.

Am I breaking some obscure security rule on php?

```
$mount -o defaults,umask=777,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,exec,username=USER,password=PASS //192.168.1.65/D /mnt/z3n-i7
$cd /mnt/z3n-i7/script
$php x.php
$PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'x.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
$cp x.php ~/x.php;cd ~;
$php x.php
SUCCESS
```

--

Strace:

```
getcwd("/mnt/z3n-i7/.httpd/~scripts/pv/pv-linux", 4096) = 49
time(NULL)                              = 1339177164
lstat64("/mnt/z3n-i7/.httpd/~scripts/pv/pv-linux/pv.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=796, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/mnt/z3n-i7/.httpd/~scripts/pv/pv-linux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/mnt/z3n-i7/.httpd/~scripts/pv", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/mnt/z3n-i7/.httpd/~scripts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=81920, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/mnt/z3n-i7/.httpd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/mnt/z3n-i7", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=49152, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/mnt", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0xbfc71038) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=796, ...}) = 0
write(2, "PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Faile"..., 131) = 131
```

Guess this is the problem: Inappropriate ioctl for device ?

Comment: Could you post the `strace` output of the failing command? (`cd /mnt/z3n-i7/script; strace -o trace.txt php x.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found out that this is a php bug when accessing a filesystem hosted on a 64-bit OS. There's no fix for this, according to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50150 , So i mounted my 64-bit windows share on a 32-bit linux machine and shared the share mounted it and it worked!

Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'noserverino' option, and the problem is settled.

example:

```
mount -o defaults,umask=777,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,exec,username=USER,password=PASS,noserverino //192.168.1.65/D /mnt/z3n-i7
```